# Css border to :hover element

Tags: html, css

I'm new to css. I want to make a replica of the menu (excluding the sub-menu part) on this page: http://www.ibta-arabia.com/

This is my progress so far: https://jsfiddle.net/yny2u85j/

This is my code for the css:

```
.menu {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #2C4059;
}

.topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #D90D29;
    color: white;
}

.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
```

I'm unable to show a red line when the mouse is hovered on the menu and put separators among the menu content as on the website I linked.

Can anyone help me tweak my css code to look more the menu on the other website?

Comment: `border-top: 2px solid #D90D29;` Its border color rather than background-color in `.topnav a:hover` and `.topnav a:active` https://jsfiddle.net/kcowhr60/1/ and add border to to ur nav

Answer (score 2):

Here you can just use css pseudo elements to show the border on top: Here is you updated fiddle code: `https://jsfiddle.net/yny2u85j/11/` and also remove border property to anchor.

```css
.menu {
                              margin: 0;
                              font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    }


                    .topnav {
                              overflow: hidden;
                              background-color: #2C4059;
                    }


                    .topnav a {
                              float: left;
                              color: white;
                              text-align: center;
                              padding: 14px 16px;
                              text-decoration: none;
                              font-size: 17px;
                              position: relative;
                    }
                    
                    .topnav a:before {
                    content: '';
                    width: 100%;
                    opacity: 0;
                    transition: all ease .3s;
                    background: #D90D29;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    height: 3px;
                    }

                    .topnav a:hover:before {
                              transition: all ease .3s;
                              opacity: 1;
                    }


                    .topnav a.active {
                              background-color: #4CAF50;
                              color: white;
                    }
```

```html
<div class="menu">

        <div class="topnav">
    <a href="#">&nbsp;</a>
                  <a href="http://www.ibta-arabia.com/"><strong>Home</strong></a>
                  <a href="http://www.ibta-arabia.com/contact-us/"><strong>Contact Us</strong></a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add border-top: 2px solid transparent in .topnav a and then border-top-color: #D90D29 in .topnav a:hover and .topnav a:active

Answer (score 1):

Check updated code with simple border style

```css
.menu {
     margin: 0;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


.topnav {
     overflow: hidden;
     background-color: #2C4059;
}


.topnav a {
     float: left;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 14px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 17px;
     border-top: 4px solid transparent;
     border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
}


.topnav a:hover {
     /*background-color: #D90D29;
     color: white; */
     border-top: 4px solid #d90d29;
}


.topnav a.active {
     background-color: #4CAF50;
     color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">

        <div class="topnav">
    <a href="#">&nbsp;</a>
                  <a href="http://www.ibta-arabia.com/"><strong>Home</strong></a>
                  <a href="http://www.ibta-arabia.com/contact-us/"><strong>Contact Us</strong></a>
        </div>
</div>
```